# OBTENER RESULTADO DE UN COUNT

Tags: c#, oracle

Tengo este query:

```
string count = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM  XXXXX.XXXXXX C WHERE C.SERIAL = :SERIAL";
```

Que ejecutando me manda en el gestor de bases de datos, me manda como resultado 6, ya que es la cantidad que existe actualmente.

Despues tengo esto:

```
    using (var adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(count, connection))
    {
         adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(":SERIAL", serial);
      valor = ?;       
   }
    if (Int32.Parse(valor) > 0)
    {
         salida = "EXISTE";
    }
    else
    {
        salida = "NO";
    }
```

Mi pregunta es como guardo el resultado de `6`, para despues poder compararlo si es mayor a 0, y saber si existe ya o no ese serial?

Comment: Prueba con `Int32 valor = (int32) adapter.SelectCommand.ExecuteScalar();`

Comment: Donde estas ejecutando la consulta? ahi debes obtener el valor